# spring quartz schedular properties autocomit exception

Tags: spring, properties, quartz-scheduler

I am using maven-java-spring with quartz schedular and spring-jdbc template.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

We have process which makes large amount of inserts using quartz scheduler job.

When i execute job after inserting x number of records it throws exception as follows

```
exception caught: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: commit() should not be called while in auto-commit mode.
                at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:270)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
```

Following is my sechdular code

```
<!-- Spring jobs -->
  <bean id="wireJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="search"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="executeWireSearch"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="nonWireJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="search"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="executeNonWireSearch"/>
  </bean>



      <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
          <list>
            <ref bean="wireQuartzTrigger"/>
            <ref bean="nonWireQuartzTrigger"/>
          </list>
        </property>
      </bean>
```

does it something to do with quartz properties related to autocomit ??

Comment: "We have process which makes large amount of inserts using quartz scheduler job" How are you inserting I mean using procedure or batch inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a look to the quartz FAQ: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-springCommit

BTW, you should upgrade if possible because 1.7 is quite old and not supported anymore

HIH

Comment: yes i am updating it to latest version, do you think after updating to latest version do i need to make any change to fix this issue ?

Comment: can't upgrade to latest version but 1.8.5 reference http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114336-What-Maven-dependencies-do-I-need-to-include-Quartz-support-Failing-with-NoClass